# How many model parameters did Microsoft's 2015 ImageNet-winner network have?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-classification, machine-learning-model

In 2015 a team of researchers from Microsoft [won](https://blogs.microsoft.com/ai/microsoft-researchers-win-imagenet-computer-vision-challenge/) the ImageNet contest with a network of 152 layers.

How many parameters did their model have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of parameters is 60,344,232, according to:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ResNet-152-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data

Although, from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf (page 6), it looks like an ensemble was used for ILSVRC 2015:

"We combine six models of different depth to form an ensemble (only with two 152-layer ones at the time of submitting). This leads to 3.57%
top-5 error on the test set (Table 5). This entry won the 1st place in ILSVRC 2015."